# Can i use in ASP.NET application with Entity a Blowfish encryption

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption

I have some experience in php developing and when i needed to use encryption to save in database the user password i used Blowfish encryption. So my question is: Can i use Blowfish again with Entity to save only the encrypted password in the database and then to check only encrpyted password when user need to login ? If the answer is yes but there are a better ways to do that, i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: actually i didn't find a way how to do it, cause i'm actually new to asp i'm googling from 3 days to find a way and no results until now. That's why i'm asking

Comment: Any encryption algorithm computes a BLOB. You can store & fetch BLOB practically with any DB system, and sql server is no different. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: If I undestand your description right you use Blowfish encryption only during autorization and after succesfully autorization you dont use encryption.

Comment: Well i'm going to tell ya like that, in php to encrypt password i used - password_hash()  then i saved the hashed password in the database. When user needed to log in, i used password_varify() to see if the password match or not. And the question is - is there a method close enough to php ones ?

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Seems like very close to that you [want](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/asp-net-mvcsimple-application-security-using-password-hashing-before-storing-it-to-database/)